# Appium Android - .clear(); is not working for password field. How to clear a password field?

Tags: android, automation, appium

**.clear()** is working for all other text fields but not for the password and confirm password fields. 
I am using Android real device.

Answer (score 0):

password field also works as normal text field. you need to cross check locator which was used fro password field.